# Why is eslint not working after migrating from CRA to Next.js?

Tags: next.js, create-react-app, eslint

I am currently working on migrating an app from CRA to Next.js. Eslint was working beautifully when using CRA (eslint works out-of-the-box).

I want to use the same CRA linting rules in the Next.js app so I installed `eslint-config-react-app`. I followed the instructions as provided on the NPM page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app:

1. npm install --save-dev eslint-config-react-app @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0 @typescript-eslint/parser@^4.0.0 babel-eslint@^10.0.0 eslint@^7.5.0 eslint-plugin-flowtype@^5.2.0 eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.0 eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.1 eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.3 eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4.0.8
2. create the .eslintrc.json file with the following content:
   `{ "extends": "react-app" }`

However, the linting is not showing up neither in the development console nor in the browser console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution.

I wanted the eslint output to show up in the console when saving edits to a file directly (just like with CRA). Initially, I did not realize that Next.js has no eslint plugin/loader specified in their webpack config so I extended theirs by adding my own. Now everything works as expected, just like it did when using CRA.

I actually used (although slightly modified) CRA's config for the `eslint-webpack-plugin` plugin. If anyone else wants to have an eslint setup in Next.js similar to CRA, add the following to your `next.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin')

const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

module.exports = {
    webpack(config) {
        config.plugins.push(new ESLintPlugin({
            // Plugin options
            extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
            eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            context: resolveApp('src'),
            cache: true,
            cacheLocation: path.resolve(
                resolveApp('node_modules'),
                '.cache/.eslintcache'
            ),
            // ESLint class options
            cwd: resolveApp('.'),
            resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
            baseConfig: {
                extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app/base')],
                rules: {},
            },
        }))

        return config
    }
}
```

Note, that when using the above you will need to install `eslint-config-react-app` and its dependencies (see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app).

Finally, note that since Next.js only renders (compiles) a page when it is needed in development, eslint will only run on a page when it is displayed in the browser as pointed out here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9904. This makes adding the following script to package.json as suggested by Roman very useful if you want to do a "full-scan" of your project.

`"lint": "eslint ."`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a command like this in the `scripts` section of your `package.json`:

```json
"lint": "eslint ."
```

And then you can check your eslint results by running:

```sh
npm run lint
```